# Google sheets - Count duplicate text in a column with conditions

Tags: google-sheets

I have an spreadsheet like this:

| product name | sold? |
| --- | --- |
| banana | FALSE |
| banana | TRUE |
| apple | TRUE |
| apple | FALSE |
| apple | FALSE |

I'd like to add another column to display the number of unsold products. so the desired result would be something like this:

| product name | sold? | available |
| --- | --- | --- |
| banana | FALSE | 1 |
| banana | TRUE | 1 |
| apple | TRUE | 2 |
| apple | FALSE | 2 |
| apple | FALSE | 2 |

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `COUNTIFS()`. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,A2,$B$2:$B,FALSE)
```

For dynamic spill result, use `MAP()` function.

```
=MAP(A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(A:A,x,B:B,FALSE)))
```

To refer full column as input, use-

```
=MAP(TOCOL(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(x,COUNTIFS(A:A,x,B:B,FALSE)))
```

[image]